# Can a load stress test (for example with Loader.io) cause a Denial of Service?

Tags: denial-of-service, load-testing, stress-testing

I want to test the performance of my server using Loader.io service, but I'm worried about the impact.
From what I understand the site will load stress my server making multiple requests, what is the limit of that? is not possible to cause a denial of service?

Comment: The limits are either the defaults, or what you configured. Communicate your testing to your ISP/hoster/[...] beforehand, otherwise they may shut you down. You can easily DoS your own server with these tools, or trigger a DoS protection of said ISP/hoster[...].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So answer is YES, @Lenniey is correct, until unless you are not defining the boundaries of your load test workflow it might kill your server. So before testing anything get the details about kind of resources, number of requests etc information to play safe.